# How to get and update azure lifecycle rules in java

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, lifecycle

I have created a lifecycle policy for azure storage account with the help of following piece of code.

```
StorageManager manager = StorageManager.authenticate(credential, subId); //credentilas and subscription iD
   manager.managementPolicies()
          .define("testprefix")
          .withExistingStorageAccount(resourceGroup, storageAcc)
          .defineRule("testprefixrulenew")
          .withLifecycleRuleType()
          .withBlobTypeToFilterFor(BlobTypes.BLOCK_BLOB)
          .withPrefixToFilterFor("prefix1")
          .withDeleteActionOnBaseBlob(1)
          .attach()
          .create();
```

when I run this, all the existing lifecycle rules for the storage account get deleted and only the newly created one is present .

**1) How to avoid this deletion of existing lifecycle rules for azure storage account using java?**

also , when I try to get the existing lifecycle policies by using following code snippet.

```
ManagementPolicyInner managementPolicy1 =
        manager2
            .inner()
            .managementPolicies()
            .getAsync(resourceGroup, storageAcc)
            .toBlocking()
            .last();
```

I am able to get only the last modified/created policy. and if we remove "last()", it gives Observable value, so.

**2) How to get the existing policies, iterate them , and update one of it if required using java???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***How to avoid this deletion of existing lifecycle rules for azure
> storage account using java?***

Regarding the issue, we can use the class `com.azure.resourcemanager.storage.implementation.StorageManagementClientImpl` to implement it. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.resourcemanager.storage.implementation.storageaccountsclientimpl?view=azure-java-stable)

for example

```
String clientId="<the service principal client id>";
        String clientSecret="<the service principal client secret>"";
        String tenant="";
        String subId="";
        AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(tenant,subId,AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
                .tenantId(tenant)
                .build();

        StorageManagementClientImpl storageManagementClient = new StorageManagementClientBuilder()
                .pipeline(HttpPipelineProvider.buildHttpPipeline(credential,profile))
                .endpoint(profile.getEnvironment().getResourceManagerEndpoint())
                .subscriptionId(profile.getSubscriptionId())
                .buildClient();

        ManagementPolicyInner policyInner= storageManagementClient.getManagementPolicies()
                .get("andywin7","andyprivate",ManagementPolicyName.DEFAULT);

        ManagementPolicyDefinition definition = new ManagementPolicyDefinition()
                .withActions( new ManagementPolicyAction().withBaseBlob(
                        new ManagementPolicyBaseBlob().withTierToCool(
                                new DateAfterModification().withDaysAfterModificationGreaterThan(180))))
                .withFilters(new ManagementPolicyFilter().withBlobTypes(Arrays.asList("blockBlob")));

        ManagementPolicyRule newRule = new ManagementPolicyRule()
                .withName("changeTier")
                .withEnabled(true)
                .withType(RuleType.LIFECYCLE)
                .withDefinition(definition);
        policyInner.policy().rules().add(newRule);
        Response<ManagementPolicyInner>  res =storageManagementClient.getManagementPolicies().createOrUpdateWithResponse(
                "andywin7","andyprivate",ManagementPolicyName.DEFAULT,
                policyInner.policy(), Context.NONE);
```

[image]
[image]

> ***How to get the existing policies, iterate them, and update one of
> it if required using java???***

Please refer to the following code
list

```
String clientId="<the service principal client id>";
        String clientSecret="<the service principal client secret>"";
        String tenant="";
        String subId="";
        AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(tenant,subId,AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
                .tenantId(tenant)
                .build();

        StorageManager manager = StorageManager.authenticate(credential,profile);
        ManagementPolicy managementPolicy = manager.managementPolicies()
                .getAsync("andywin7","andyprivate")
                .block();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        for ( ManagementPolicyRule rule : managementPolicy.policy().rules()){

            System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(rule));
        }
```

Update

```
String clientId="<the service principal client id>";
        String clientSecret="<the service principal client secret>"";
        String tenant="";
        String subId="";
        AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(tenant,subId,AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
                .tenantId(tenant)
                .build();

        StorageManager manager = StorageManager.authenticate(credential,profile);
        ManagementPolicy managementPolicy = manager.managementPolicies()
                .getAsync("andywin7","andyprivate")
                .block();
        managementPolicy.update()
                .updateRule("<the rule name you want to update>")
                     ... the action you want to update
                .parent()
                .withoutRule("<the rule name you do not want to update>")
                .apply();
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/resourcemanager/azure-resourcemanager-storage/src/test/java/com/azure/resourcemanager/storage/StorageManagementPoliciesTests.java)

---

**Update**

Regarding how to update the existing rule, please refer to the fowwing code

```
        StorageManager manager = StorageManager.authenticate(credential,profile);
        ManagementPolicy managementPolicy = manager.managementPolicies()
                .getAsync("andywin7","andyprivate")
                .block();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        for ( ManagementPolicyRule rule : managementPolicy.policy().rules()){
               System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(rule));

               if(rule.name().equals("deleteAppend")){
                  int i= managementPolicy.policy().rules().indexOf(rule);
                   ManagementPolicyRule newRule= managementPolicy.policy().rules().get(i);
                   managementPolicy.policy().rules().remove(rule);
                   newRule.definition()
                           .actions()
                           .withBaseBlob(new ManagementPolicyBaseBlob().withDelete(new DateAfterModification().withDaysAfterModificationGreaterThan(18) ));
                   managementPolicy.policy().rules().add(newRule);
               }


        }

        managementPolicy.update()
                .withPolicy(managementPolicy.policy())
                .apply();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell which gradle or maven dependencies are you using ???

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution @Jim Xu . 

I was using the incorrect dependencies, and hence that `block()` was giving error, its resolved now.  

but Facing one more issue , while updating existing policy , I have given this - `.updateRule("rule1")` and `withoutRule("Rule2")`   

here, **Rule1** got updated but **Rule2** and other **Rule3** got deleted.  
is it the behavior of update(), or am I doing something wrong??

Comment: @DeveloperSSP208 Hi. I made a mistake. the method `withoutRule` will remove the rule. Regarding how to update, please refer to  my update.

Comment: Hi @Jim Xu, while creating or updating lifecycle rule , this `manager.managementPolicies()
                .getAsync("andywin7","andyprivate")`   and  `storageManagementClient.getManagementPolicies()
                .get("andywin7","andyprivate",ManagementPolicyName.DEFAULT)`  will give an exception of **"ManagementPolicyNotFound"**  if there is no lifecycle rule present for the storage account , Can you please suggest how to handle it?

Comment: @DeveloperSSP208 I think you can use `try{}catch{}` to catch the exception.

Comment: yes @Jim Xu,  I tried adding try catch block ...but further its giving same exception for ManagementPolicyInner instance which we need to add rule in policy : `policyInner =storageManagementClient.getManagementPolicies().get(resourceGroup, storageAcc, ManagementPolicyName.DEFAULT);`    how to avoid this then ? How to create ManagementPolicyInner istance for very first lifecycle rule?